# how to access movie clip inside mask layer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

i have layer with action script code.
example of part of the code..

```
var allMC = new Array();
allMC[0] = allitems_1.item_1;
allMC[1] = allitems_1.item_2;
allMC[2] = allitems_1.item_3;
allMC[3] = allitems_1.item_4;
```

this code store reference to mc inside an array.
everything is working perfect.

but when i convert this layer to mask layer and run the flash it says:

Scene 1, Layer 'background', Frame 1, Line 56   1120: Access of undefined property allitems_1.

*allitems1 is also the name i set for the movie clip instance on the stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `ActionScript` on a separate layer from your mask layer. It's generally considered good practice when working on the timeline to have a layer specifically for your `ActionScript` and labelled as such.

Comment: it dosent help...
i did put it on a diffrent layer. i called it background.

Comment: Is the allitems_1 instance on the layer you're converting to a mask? If so, you probably want to put it onto the layer below ie. the layer you're masking.